# how to avoid R generating huge fonts in svg

Tags: r, svg

When I call upon svg(‘filename.svg’) for R plots, sometimes it turns out ok, other times it results in huge font size

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10 + runif(10)

svg(filename="plot1.svg", width=5, height=5)
plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

When open the svg in illustrator fonts are huge and become giant ink blobs
[image]

Anyone has encountered the same before?